# i want to make a markup tag in html not executing by browser?

Tags: php, html

i want to make a markup tag in html not executing by browser???

so i keep information in it i want to parse it later

for example

```
<img src='<?=$photo;?>' class='image' border='0' width='220' height='170'/></a>
```

i want to fetch $photo later so i want to move it to another markup tag which not executing by browser

Comment: That's nice. What will you be doing with it?

Comment: @Ignacio you made me laugh man

Comment: How are you going to fetch it? With JavaScript? Why not set the URL as JS variable then? Or how do you gonna do it?

Comment: You could just write it in notepad and leave it on your desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it inside of a comment.

```
<!-- markup goes here -->
```

Or you could give it an id and use css to display:none

```
<tag id="tag1"></tag>
tag#tag1 { display: none; }
```

Or you could use style

```
<tag style="display:none"></tag>
```

Comment: Problem when using `IE` it executed

Answer (score 2):

You could first encode the content of the markup tag and then put that encoded tag inside a hidden input. When the page posted at server, you could then decode the tag and do processing as required.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your page compliant, you could assign that data to javascript variables, or you could put it in whatever tags you want and either css style those tags as hidden or comment them out...

```
<!-- <myTag>My data is here </myTag> -->

<div style='display:none'>My data is here</div>

<script>
var myData='This is my data I can access it via javascipt';
</script>
```